# How do you add css to a Kotlin JS project?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, kotlin-js

I created a new Kotlin/JS Gradle project using the wizard in IntelliJ.

I'm unclear how I'm supposed to add `css` to the project. The [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/js-project-setup.html#configuring-css) explains how to enable `css` webpack support, but it doesn't actually say how to add the `css` file into your project (i.e., how to use the file).

For example, in a normal project, you would just import it in a javascript file. Since I am writing in Kotlin, how do I do it now?

Comment: Actually it does.

Comment: The documentation explains exactly how to use the CSS: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/js-project-setup.html#configuring-css . Did you follow it thoroughly?

Comment: Updated link: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/js-project-setup.html#css

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The current documentation is not very precise about this. There are actually two cases:

#### Importing CSS from existing packages

You can pretty easily import CSS files from other Node-modules using the require() function:

```
import kotlinext.js.require
import kotlinx.browser.document
import react.dom.h1
import react.dom.render

fun main() {
    require("bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css")
    render(document.getElementById("root")) {
        h1 { +"Hello"}
    }
}
```

For this to work, you need to specify `cssSupport.enabled = true` in your Gradle build, just like described in the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/js-project-setup.html#css). CSS imported this way will be processed by Webpack.

#### Incorporating your own CSS into the Webpack build

This seems to be a bit tricky right now. The KotlinJS plugin doesn't copy any resources to the Webpack's build directory (`build/js/packages/<project_name>`) by default and I didn't find any obvious configuration option for this. To solve it, you have to tell Webpack where it can find your styles:

Create `webpack.conf.d` directory in project's root and put inside some JS file containing:

`config.resolve.modules.push("<your_stylesheet_dir>");`

This config will be picked up by the KotlinJS plugin and merged into the generated `build/js/packages/<project_name>/webpack.config.js`. With this configuration you can just `require()` project's styles like in the example above. It is kind of mentioned in the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/js-project-setup.html#webpack-bundling).

Alternatively you can tweak the Gradle build, so it copies the stylesheets into the Webpack's build dir:

```
task("copyStylesheets", Copy::class) {
    from(kotlin.sourceSets["main"].resources) {
        include("styles/**")
    }
    into("${rootProject.buildDir}/js/packages/${kotlin.js().moduleName}")
    // kotlin { js { moduleName = "xyz" }} has to be set for this to work 
}
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinJsDce::class) {
    dependsOn("copyStylesheets")
}
```

Comment: You can use `into("${rootProject.buildDir}/js/packages/${rootProject.name}-${project.name}")` to avoid setting `moduleName`

Comment: In my system, using kotlin multiplatform, everything you place inside jsMain/resources is automatically copied to `build/js/packages/<project_name>/kotlin`

Answer (score 0):

Simply sticking a CSS file into `main/resources` and referencing it in index.html worked for both `browserDevelopmentRun` and serving the production build, statically.  The CSS file appears in `build/distributions`.

My build:

```kotlin
kotlin("js") version "1.7.20"
```

index.html

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
```

`index.css` is in the same resource folder as `index.html`.

This also works for images anything else, apparently.